# missing POST data in Django view

Tags: python, django, post

I'm trying to pass some login data to a view in a Django app but I'm getting no POST data to the view.  First the template with the login interface.

```
<form method="post" action="login">
{% csrf_token %}
    Username<input type="text" name="username"><br />
    Password<input type="password" name="password"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Next, I'm passing this to my login view which is defined as follows in my views.py, this is where the problem happens.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
def login(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    #logic with directing user to the login page again or to the access they need
```

On the line where I try to assign to the username variable, I get the error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /minion/login
"Key 'username' not found in <Querydict: {}>"
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/minion/login
Django Version: 1.5.1
```

The weird thing is that in the Request Information section of the page it says that there's no POST information or GET information.  I'm not sure A. Why it says the request method is GET since I specified POST in the template and B. Why there's no POST or GET data.  If anyone knows something I might be missing about using POST data in Django/Python or need another piece of info that'd be great.  Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:  Some progress.
I managed to get the pages to load through the Reverse error from the first suggestion by putting in the full path.  The crux of my problem at this point is figuring out how to make the form data get to the view function as POST instead of GET.

EDIT: Here's my urls.py file in the application directory

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('Minion.views',
    url(r'^$', 'home'),
    url(r'^login/$', 'login'),
    #some other unrelated pages are here, I haven't done anything with them yet though
)
```

Comment: change action to `{% url login %}`

Comment: that gives me a NoReverseMatch error

Comment: well.. update it to the appropriate URL name. I just showed you an example

Comment: The URL name is 'login', which is what I used.

Comment: Oh.. you need to enclose the view code in `if request.POST:` that way, it would hit that code only when there is a submit

Comment: I'm not making it to the view code, it's hitting the error in the template code.

Comment: The stacktrace you are showing is corresponding to the suggested fix. Check the answer @oleg has posted

Answer (score 7):

You are being redirected.

Your form action (ie destination) is just `login`. But the default configuration of Django is to end all URLs with a final slash, and redirect if the URL does not do that: so the browser is being redirected from `/login` to `/login/`. A redirection is always a GET, so the POST data is lost.

Use `action="/login/"` and all will be well.

Comment: I still have a GET method with this suggestion

Answer (score 2):

It seems that You have GET request instead of POST or after or before

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/minion/login
```

I think You should have check for request method

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    # otherwise create page with form or redirect
```

There is possibility that POST request is unexpected and is done by some kind of redirect (for example absence of trailing slash can cause redirect) You shoud care about this case.

Comment: for completeness - in the HTML form - set the attribute `method='post'" and then your request will be post rather than get

Comment: as I can see he has such a string `<form method="post" action="login">`

Comment: while this does prevent the error it also keeps my view from doing anything that I need it to.  i need the app to use post.

Comment: ok As I understand You have done POST request to {% url login %}  can You provide urls.py? Django redirects You (i think because of trailing slash) and You made GET request. You should use correct url to avoid redirection in this case

Answer (score 1):

Changed action to "{% 'Minion.views.authUser' %} and changed the view function to authUser because it was conflicting with the imported login function from the auth module and everything started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will work sure in your views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       data = request.POST
       username = data['username']
       password = data['password']
       user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```